# Does solubility of acetic acid depend on the pH?

Tags: solubility, ph

Does the solubility of acetic acid increase or decrease in water if I adjust the pH?

Conversely, a water-insoluble molecule (like retinol), can its solubility be increased by adjustment of the pH?

I would say no (in both cases) because the protonating or deprotonating these molecules does not change their overall hydrophilic or hydrophobic character.

Comment: Acetic acid is miscible with water, so it's solubility definitely can't be increased ;) It's solubility simply won't be affected by pH. If retinol could be protinated, that would increase it's solubility, but it can't be protinated or deprotinated to any significant degree so it's going to be insoluble in water regardless of pH.

Comment: If you increase the pH some acetate will precipitate eventually. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in both cases, though your reasoning isn't quite on target.

Regardless of the pH, retinol will not be protonated or deprotonated to any significant degree (which would greatly affect it's solubility if it were). It's just a nonpolar molecule that will stay that way regardless of pH.

Acetic acid also would not be protonated to any significant degree at low pH, but that's a mute point as it's fully miscible in water anyway.

The one situation in which you would see deprotonation of the compound is that of acetic acid at high pH. For the most part, both acetic acid and the acetate ion produced by the basic conditions should remain highly soluble. It is possible however, that if you added enough strong base, say NaOH, to a concentrated solution of acetic acid, you could eventually precipitate sodium acetate.

**Summary, TL;DR:**
You are correct that the answer to both questions is no. Acetic acid is miscible with water (so it's solubility definitely can't be increased) and it's solubility simply won't be affected by pH. If retinol could be protonated or deprotonated, that would increase it's solubility, but it can't be protonated or deprotonated to any significant degree so it is insoluble in water, regardless of pH.

Comment: How about an emulsifying agent such as ascorbylpalmitate?

Comment: @TMOTTM , sorry to have neglected your comment. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking with respect to using an emulsifying agent with two fully miscible liquids. If you are referring to affecting the solubility of retinol, I'm don't think that would have much effect in this case, but that's really just a gut feeling.

Comment: I ment, does the pH affect the solubility of emulsifying agents?

Answer (score 1):

For the two specific substances, read the other answers and comments, they answer that part.

> I would say no (in both cases) because the protonating or deprotonating these molecules does not change their overall hydrophilic or hydrophobic character.

When you protonate or deprotonate a neutral molecule, you get an ion. This will allow ion-dipole interactions with water and change the solute:solvent interactions. In liquid-liquid extraction, you get very different results at different pH values of the aqueous solution. So in general, solubility in water does change a lot with protonation state.

As an aside, retinol could be protonated or deprotonated in solvents other than water, and then you would expect a change in solubility. According to [this source](https://foodb.ca/compounds/FDB013828), you would have to go outside of the -2.2 to 16.44 pH range to achieve that (and these numbers are theoretical predictions).